# Can we add two integer variable names in C# rather than values?

Tags: c#

In c # i'm trying to add two different integer name, is it possible

```
int variablename;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Objectname.variablename+i
}
```

Comment: What is `Objectname`? And what is meant by `integer name`?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: i'm calling variable  throgh the object ,
"objectname' it is an object
'variablename' it is an integer field

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant. C# is strongly typed programming language. What you can do, is to use Dictionary for example, like this:

```
  Dictionary<string, int> names = new Dictionary<string,int>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
      names.Add(String.Format("name{0}", i.ToString()), i);
  }

  var xx1 = names["name1"];
  var xx2 = names["name2"];
  var xx3 = names["name3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to get the name of your variable and then change the name for each instance based on the iteration, thus you want to add a numeric value to the name. You can achieve this as follows:

```
string testVariable = "";
int i = 1;

// Get the name of your variable. This will result in "testVariable" as value.
string nameOfTestVariable = nameof(testVariable);

// Now add your integer to the name, but add it as a string.
nameOfTestVariable += i.ToString();

//Result, value of nameOfTestVariable: "testVariable1"
```

To get the datatype of your variable instead:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;

string dataTypesOfVariables = a.GetType().Name;    
dataTypesOfVariables += b.GetType().Name;

//Result, value of dataTypesOfVariables: "Int32Int32"
```

Comment: hi Jurjen,
 The above code is working fine 
but i need integer varibale  not a string

Comment: @SuneelSandara I am not sure I understand. If you want to add the names of the variables, you will always get a string (because we are talking about names here, not integer values). Or if you just want numeric values, you can just add the integers?

Comment: I understand, i'm taking about the data type, i need integer datatype variable name

Comment: @SuneelSandara not sure if I understand, but if you want to get the name of the datatype as string (e.g. "Int32" for an `int`), see my edit.

Comment: ok Thanku so much

Comment: @SuneelSandara you're welcome! Hope this solved your problem. Don't forget to mark my answer as solved if this fixed your problem!